# Lambda reading constexpr value without capturing it inside gmock matcher

Tags: c++, lambda, googlemock

According to [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing it if the variable (...) is constexpr and has no mutable members

In the example below I believe that `constexpr int cInt = 1234;` is such a variable.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

using testing::Eq;
using testing::Matches;

TEST(xxx, zzz)
{
    constexpr int cInt = 1234;
    auto scenario = []()
    {
        if (cInt == 1234) { std::cout << "1234 check\n"; }
        if (Matches(Eq(1234))(cInt)) { std::cout << "1234 matcher check\n"; }
    };
}
```

Yet both newest gcc and clang reject that code, if I use the `constexpr` variable inside gmock matcher expression `Matches(Eq(1234))(cInt))`. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nKWPExK4n).

```
<source>:13:31: error: 'cInt' is not captured
   13 |         if (Matches(Eq(1234))(cInt)) { std::cout << "1234 matcher check\n"; }
      |                               ^~~~
<source>:10:22: note: the lambda has no capture-default
   10 |     auto scenario = []()
      |                      ^
<source>:9:19: note: 'constexpr const int cInt' declared here
    9 |     constexpr int cInt = 1234;
```

For gcc 7.3 [this code is OK](https://godbolt.org/z/YzWa8Yeje).

MSVC rejects even this:

```
    constexpr int cInt = 1234;
    auto scenario = []()
    {
        if (cInt == 1234) { std::cout << "1234 check\n"; }
    };
```

but it's microsoft software, so I am not really surprised.

Is it the bug in the compilers, or rather something wrong on the googletest side? I am not sure if and where it should be reported.

Comment: Problem is that `static` is missing: https://godbolt.org/z/zq937n8P4 here is good demo of this issue: [from Jason Turner](https://youtu.be/4pKtPWcl1Go)

Comment: Offtopic: you gtest is strangely written. Use `TEST_F` macro with respective class to organize code better: https://godbolt.org/z/E4GEWfTs8

Comment: Thanks! I will watch the video as well. BTW, which compiler is "right" in this case?

Answer (score 0):

*constexpr* is not required to be a compile-time object, it **MAY** be a compile-time object

I encountered this circumstance in the past when worked with MSVC and it gave absolutely the same story by turning my *constexpr* value into a *const* value (discovered this behaviour when going over code within debugger, the memory for *constexpr value* was allocated by MSVC on stack), so this is why here it is not captured by lambda, since it is not global

As you've been already advised you should mark it *static constexpr* to reveal this value in lambda function

Comment: Thanks, that explains why different compilers somehow treat it differently under different circumstances. However, is it mentioned in standard (like it was mentioned in cppreference), whether C++ code using `constexpr` value in lambda (without capturing it), is correct, or not? How the compilers manage things internally is one thing, but code correctness should be a universal concept, right?

Comment: @pptaszni where did you see that `constexpr` variable defined in the function, that might be converted in a `const` value allocated on stack, must be visible in a lambda? I haven't seen such a claim anywhere

Comment: @pptaszni be aware that `constexpr` value that might be converted in `const` value in global scope and in function-local scope are absolutely two different things, because global scope is generally seen and captured by lambda functions

Comment: [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), under "captures", like quoted in my question. However, I didn't find the same mention under [expr.prim.lambda.capture], but maybe I didn't look good enough.

Comment: Actually, I tried some example of implicit capture from C++17 standard ("OK: calls #1, does not capture x"): `void f(int){} int main(){ const int x = 7; [](){ f(x); }(); }` and it compiles with gcc, but fails with MSVC. So it seems there is some inconsistency, I am just not sure what is the "right" compiler behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the call operator on the `Matches` object takes its parameter by reference (presumably reference to const, though it could also be a universal reference). This is an odr-use, i.e. `cInt` object is being used for its address rather than its value.

Consider that as far as the language is aware, `Matches` might be looking at the address of its argument, so it matters whether that argument is a temporary copy, or the actual `cInt` object existing within the stack frame of the `TEST(xxx, zzz)` function. In the latter case, `cInt` would need to have been captured by reference.

You can work around this by explicitly performing prvalue materialization on `cInt`, e.g. using [the `auto` operator (since C++23)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) or, for compatibility with obsolete compilers, the unary plus `+` operator, so that the value of `cInt` is materialized to a temporary, and that temporary is passed by reference to `Matches`:

```
    if (Matches(Eq(1234))(auto(cInt))) { std::cout << "1234 matcher check\n"; }
    //                    ^~~~~    ~
```

or

```
    if (Matches(Eq(1234))(+cInt)) { std::cout << "1234 matcher check\n"; }
    //                    ^
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T8GoKGTE8).